# What is the difference between python Console and a python terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, console

I understand that you can run a python shell/console from a terminal, but I don't really understand what is the fundamental difference between a shell and a terminal.

Comment: Shell is a program which processes commands and returns output , like bash in Linux . Terminal is a program that run a shell. For more info: https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal

Comment: hey thanks, that one helped.